# Dapper Extensions dbConnection.Get<Object>

Tags: entity-framework, mapping, dapper, prefix, dapper-extensions

Problem with: Dapper Extensions dbConnection.Get(personId)

I have a model called Person:

```
Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In the database I have this table:

```
data.Persons
    Pers_Id
    Pers_Name
```

When I try this without any kind of custom mapping, I get an error "Invalid object name 'Person'."
I believe this is a mapping issue, because when I completely map the model with the prefix 'Pers_', and use 'data.Persons'
Get works.

But is there a way to automatically map with a prefix? The database I'm using has many different tables
with different prefices.

I also have everything already mapped to Entity framework. Is there a possibility of getting the map settings from
Entity DbModelBuilder?

Answer (score 1):

Dapper-Extensions is convention based. For schema, it uses .dbo and for primary key it uses Id. If your tables don't match the convention, you will have to create a [custom mapping](https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions/wiki/Customized-mapping-for-a-class).

```
public class MyModelMapper : ClassMapper<MyModel>
{
    public MyModelMapper()
    {

        //use different table name
        Table("table_name");

        //use a custom schema
        Schema("not_dbo_schema"); 

        //have a custom primary key
        Map(x => x.ThePrimaryKey).Key(KeyType.Assigned);

        //Use a different name property from database column
        Map(x=> x.Foo).Column("Bar");

        //Ignore this property entirely
        Map(x=> x.SecretDataMan).Ignore();

        //optional, map all other columns
        AutoMap();
    }
}
```

An alternative is to use Dapper and just write your inline queries:

```
connection.Query("select * from foo.table where myId = {myId}", new {myId})
```

**Update:**

Another alternative is to play around with [Code Generation and T4 Text Templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx)

Here is a trivial [example](http://teamyudin.blogspot.com/2012/06/database-tables-to-c-poco-classes-t4.html)

Comment: Is there anyway to autogenerate or set rules for a custom mapper? I have maybe 100 tables and I don't want to create that many mappers...

Comment: I update the answer. I'm not aware of anything that will just do it for you, but you can write your own code generator.